# How to split a unique string in many others strings with a maximum char length

Tags: javascript, string

I'm building a project and I want to pick up a big string and transform it on some other strings.
Assuming that the bigger string has 320 characters and the string character max length is 280 (example).
I want to split it in a string with 280 chars and other with the remaining chars (40).
(Language: Javascript)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For your case, the answer using .substr() seems more helpful. But if you need to split a string in multiple chunks of a certain size, you can do something like this. It will return an array containing the substrings.

```js
function chunkSubstr(str, size) {
  const numChunks = Math.ceil(str.length / size)
  const chunks = new Array(numChunks)

  for (let i = 0, o = 0; i < numChunks; ++i, o += size) {
    chunks[i] = str.substr(o, size)
  }
  console.log(chunks)
}

let str = "hghib  egfibrhfoibfrbhubvgcqy gfwbrrhhvfebvoifieqbvouhbef"
chunkSubstr(str, 30)
```

Comment: Yes. Actually the medium of character size of my strings are 500 chars and splitting it into multiple parts will help me so much. Thanks man

Answer (score -1):

The substr() method returns a portion of the string, starting at the specified index and extending for a given number of characters afterwards.
Let's suppose the length of str is 320 characters.

```
const str = 'Mozilla';

console.log(str.substr(0, 280));    
console.log(str.substr(280));
```